# Mongoose find, execute logic, then update on the same collection

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find a document, check some condition on its fields and perform an action or another depending on the outcome of a condition. This is inside a request handling so I must return different things in the response depending on the outcomes.

I have a solution done with findOneAndUpdate and if the returned records are 0 I return an error status, but I am curious to understand why the following doesn't work:

```
Users.findOne({'username':someVariable}).then((output)=>{

     if(output.someFiled > someCondition){
          Users.update(
              {'username':someVariable},
              {$set: {....}}
          ).then((error, num, success) =>{
              if(success){
                  return res.status(200).send('UPDATE OK');
              }
              if(error){
                  return res.status(500).....;
              }
          });
     } else {
         return res.status(404).....;
     }        

}).catch(....;
```

In particular the Users.update inside the find.then always return num:

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

Which means that no records were found although the record was indeed found with the first findOne.

EDIT: more information about the libraries, as maybe it's a matter of updating them (from package.json):

```
"bluebird": "^3.4.6",
"mongodb": "^3.0.2",
"mongoose": "^4.12.4",
```

Thanks, T.

Comment: promises for mongoose is deprecated. Try using `Users.findOne({'username':someVariable}).then((err, output)=>...`. If it still doesn't work, please provide us with more information such as what your output is what your conditions are, etc

Comment: I see, this project is a legacy one I am revamping so maybe the problem is just weird libraries.     then((err, output) =>....     returns the user in the "err" object and undefined in output. I am adding some more information about the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: the model file of the User didn't have the fields I was trying to update. The "find" part works also if the model has no declaration of such fields, but the "update" part won't.

So yea, just like that, should have read all the code but I thought it was boring.. never lucky.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `(err,output)` in `findOne`

```
Users.findOne({'username':someVariable}).then((err,output)=>{

     if(output.someFiled > someCondition){
          Users.update(
              {'username':someVariable},
              {$set: {....}}
          ).then((error, num, success) =>{
              if(success){
                  return res.status(200).send('UPDATE OK');
              }
              if(error){
                  return res.status(500).....;
              }
          });
     } else {
         return res.status(404).....;
     }        

}).catch(....;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it's not working as expected, err contains the user and output is undefined. Maybe it's a problem with the libraries, I've added some details on packages in the question